# Preserving zoom after rerender with D3 v5 and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm building an app containing a Force Layout tree that's supposed to re-render every time the user clicks on a node (this is not negotiable).
I've implemented the zoom and it works as expected.

For the tree's first run, I am manually calculating its coordinates and rescaling it so everything is visible without zooming out.
After the first render, I'm saving the coordinates of the tree after every zoom event and reapplying it when it's rebuilt. Everything works just fine, AS LONG AS scaling is 1.
When it's different, the coordinates get messed up and I'm not able to keep the tree in the same position as before the re-render.

How would I be able to keep the exact same translation / scaling as before?

One thing I observed is that the coordinates seem to have been multiplied by the scale, hence the wrongful change of position.

Here's the code:

```
// Adds the zoom event listener and saves the last coordinates / scale
const zoom = d3.zoom().on('zoom', () => {
  const newTransform = d3.event.transform;

  SVGGroup.attr('transform', newTransform);

  setPreviousTransform(newTransform);
});


// Runs after every render to apply either the initial position/scale calculated by me or the existing one
let transform = null;
  if (previousTransform) {
    transform = d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(previousTransform.k)
      .translate(previousTransform.x, previousTransform.y);
  } else {
    transform = d3.zoomIdentity.scale(ratio).translate(x, y);
  }
```

Comment: 6 months later, did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Yes, but the issue was probably related to something specific to my setup. As I mentioned, the coordinates were being multiplied by the current zoom, so the results would be slightly off if the zoom were low or astronomically far from expected if the zoom was higher. Check my answer below. Hope that helps clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates were being multiplied by the current zoom, so the results would be slightly off if the zoom were low or astronomically far from expected if the zoom was higher. Dividing those values by the zoom scale eliminates the problem.

```
const transform = previousTransform
  ? d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(previousTransform.k)
      .translate(
        previousTransform.x / previousTransform.k,
        previousTransform.y / previousTransform.k
      )
  : d3.zoomIdentity.translate(x, y);
```